# Probability of system failure within one week

Tags: probability

Suppose components A, B1 and B2 operate independently, in a system below, and the
probabilities that any one of the components will operate for one week without failure
are $P(A) = P(B_1) = 0.9$ and $P(B_2) = 0.8$.

The System works if A works and either B1 or B2 works.

```
a.) Find the probability that the entire system will operate without failure for one week
b.) Suppose B1 failed within one week. Find the probability  that the entire system will operate without failure for one week.
```

My Work:

a.) P(A ∩ B) = P(A) * P(B) = 0.9 * 0.8 = 0.72 or 72%

b.) P(A ∪ B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A ∩ B) = (0.9 + 0.8) - 0.72
= 1.7 - 0.72 = 0.98 or 98%

The problem is that I do not know whether these answers are correct and they do not look right to me. For a, system success is only 72% even though both success rates for B1 and B2 are quite high and for question b, 92% seems too high.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Here's a hint to get you started: P(B) is not the smaller of P(B1) and P(B2); it is P(B1 ∪ B2), i.e. the probability that either B1 or B2 is working.

Comment: do you mean that for question A use P(B1 ∪ B2) rather than ∩ ?

Comment: I mean that everywhere you have the probability of B, it should be the probability of (B1 ∪ B2). For example, P(A ∩ B) = P(A ∩ (B1 ∪ B2)) where P(B1) is 0.9 and P(B2) is 0.8, as you mentioned.

Comment: I think this is not the case, since component A is either fail/not fail depending on B1 and B2. so the question is basically asking for the probability of success of the system given B1 and B2?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point of view. What value are you using for P(B)?

Comment: How i see it is, A is irrelevant here because it is either a 1 or a 0 depending on B1 and B2. If B1 or B2 does not fail, then A works and the system does not fail for the week. If B1 and B2 fails then A will fail, thus, the system fails. I understand that A is not the system, but a component of it, but since it is kind of like the entire system itself fails depending on B1 and B2, the only events you need to calculate are with B1 and B2. sorry if that did not make sense

Comment: OH NO! sorry, i misread the question. I have it now, thanks

Comment: Essentially. a duplicate of `http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941498/probability-that-a-system-will-last-more-than-500-hours`. Different numbers, same logic.

Answer (score 0):

a)

$$\Pr(\text{no failure})=\Pr(A \cap(B_1\cup B_2))=P(A)\left(P(B_1)+P(B_2)\right)$$

b) set $P(B_1)=0$

$$\Pr(\text{no failure})=\Pr(A \cap B_2)=P(A)P(B_2)$$